# How to enable firewalld without breaking application?

Tags: centos, firewall, firewalld

I have multiple CentOS 7 machines in the same LAN. Each one is communicating with a few others and having one or more applications installed that each listen on various ports (database, webserver, load-balancing service etc.). Typical web-architecture stuff.

Now `firewalld` is disabled on all of them. And I want to enable it everywhere.

Normally it would go something like:

1. `systemctl enable firewalld`
2. `systemctl start firewalld`
3. `firewall-cmd <...>` (add ports, sources, services etc.)

The problem is that, once I start firewalld service, by default it blocks most of my stuff<sup>1</sup>, until I get the chance to do the 3rd step. And, given the big number of configurations (ports, sources) I have to add, my services will basically become unusable/unreachable until I figure it out.

I'm most concerned of some of these features:

- I use GlusterFS on some machines to create a network-file-system which I then mount on other machines
- I use Corosync+Pacemaker to create a couple of clusters between some of the machines; these tools use various ports for heartbeat-like functionality

If I turn on firewalld on these machines, it would immediately block all these services, until I get the chance to execute my many `firewall-cmd <...>` statements. And I don't know the consequences of that.

---

My question is: Is there some way to execute the 3rd step BEFORE the 2nd step? So that everything is in place when I turn on the service.

My one single idea is to somehow manually edit the XML files in the `/etc/firewalld/zones` folder. But it seems extremely error-prone, especially since I'm not that familiar with firewalld to be confortable making such edits.

---

<sup>1</sup> = From what I know, only ports 80/443 (HTTP/HTTPS) and 22 (SSH) will be opened, all others are blocked until you explicitly open them.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start `firewalld` service you should specify parameters via config files.
I recommend to you to create file of rules for every service (GlusterFS, Pacemaker ...) and put in the file all ports that you need. For example (for pacemaker got from [Configuring the iptables Firewall to Allow Cluster Components](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/s1-firewalls-haar)) `/etc/firewalld/services/pacemaker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>Pacemaker</short>
  <description>Pacemaker service</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2224"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="3121"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="5403"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="5404"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="5405"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="21064"/>
</service>
```

More info with examples you can got from [How To Set Up a Firewall Using FirewallD on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7).

Then you can start `firewalld` safely.

If you are afraid of break `firewalld` by editing zone files by hand you can test in virtual environment before apply in working system.

Comment: So you're saying you can manually add such files in `/etc/firewalld/services` and they will be read/loaded when you turn on firewalld? Interesting, that might work. I'll take a closer look, thanks.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Yes it will be read/reloaded when you turn on firewall via `systemctl start firewalld` or reload config via `firewall-cmd --reload`. I took this info from "How To Set Up a Firewall Using FirewallD on CentOS 7".

Comment: Wouldn't `firewall-offline-cmd <...>` be a better fit here? I didn't know it existed, just found it in the man-pages a few minutes ago...

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just add the option `--permanent` to all your rules, e.g.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-port=1234/tcp --permanent
```

This will register rules in the permanent configuration but won't apply them, until you run the command

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

---

By the way, this is the recommended way to operate `firewalld`; if you don't use the `--permanent` option, changes will be applied temporarily and will be erased at the next firewall reload or restart.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting it wrong, but I think the question was how to do this without actually having to start `firewalld` first.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My mistake.